# Why is my CPU so busy sometimes even when I run just the web browser

Tags: cpu

I use Ubuntu 16:04 I've attached screenshots of the System app taken at about the same time.

https://s16.postimg.org/7samm6p4l/system.png and 
https://s13.postimg.org/quu09eahj/system2.png

Comment: What make you say that your CPU is busy ? 4 processes are using in all 24% of a core.

Comment: Compiz is just the window manager, web content is linked to the Firefox and there's just the System app whose screenshots are posted.

Comment: The whole system runs very slowly and has got a serious lag because of this problem.